# How to make dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I find this dropdown menu on internet.The problem is dropdown is always open and it doesnt work.When i paste all default code from http://codepen.io/Jeplaa/pen/IzAvx
it doesn't work.Please can you help me.How i can make when user click button it show dropdown menu and stay until user click on button again.

I include 2 scripts

```
 <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script src="assets/js/menu.js"></script>
```

Also the the code of dropdown menu:

```js
$( ".cog, .admin-text" ).on( "click", function()
{
  $( ".menu" ).stop().fadeToggle( "fast" );
});
```

```css
/*MENU CSS------------*/
.top {
        background-color:#F8F8F8;
        width:100%;
        height:60px;
       -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 8px -200px rgba(178,176,176,1);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 8px -200px rgba(178,176,176,1);
        box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 8px -200px rgba(178,176,176,1);
}

.profile_img {
    max-width: 28px;
    max-height: 32px;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.content
{
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
 width: 250px;
 margin-left:30px;
}
.user_text {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:20px;
    vertical-align:20%;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.admin-panel
{
 background: #F8F8F8;
 width: 240px;
 height: 40px;
 color: #888;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 font: bold 13px Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 41px;
 cursor: default;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
}

.down
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 10px 14px 0 0;
 border: none;
 color: #888888;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.down:hover { color: #555555; }

.user_text { cursor: pointer; }

.menu a
{
 display: block;
 background: #F8F8F8;
 width: 240px;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 font: bold 13px Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
 color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.4 );
 line-height: 40px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.menu a:nth-child( 2 )
{
 border-top-left-radius: 3px;
 border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.menu a:last-child
{
 border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.menu a:hover { color: #555555; }

.menu a:hover > .octicon { color: #555555; }

.arrow
{
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin-left: 15px;
 border-left: 7px solid transparent;
 border-right: 7px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 9px solid #F8F8F8;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300">
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

<div class="top">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="admin-panel"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wmyOI5f.jpg" class="profile_img"><b class="user_text">Curtis Jackson</b></div> <span class="down"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/bLXw2RL.png"></span>
                    <div class="menu">
                        <div class="arrow"></div> 
                        <a href="#">Edit User</a> 
                        <a href="#">Worker Statistics</span></a> 
                        <a href="#">Settings</span></a> 
                        <a href="#">Logout</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: dropdown menus are very simple. just check w3schools ( http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp ) or use bootstrap http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use in JQ

```
 $( ".cog, .admin-text" ).on( "click", function()
   {
    $( ".menu" ).stop().fadeToggle( "fast" );
   });
```

`.cog` and `.admin-text` do not exist in your HTML . i guess you want your `.menu` to appear ( fadeIn ) after you click the `.arrow` or on the text with class ".user_text"

also you say that the `.menu` always appears, ofcourse that happens if you don't hide it. in this example i've hidden it by setting `{display:none}` in CSS

see code below

let me know if this is what you want.

```js
$(".down,.user_text").click(function(){
   $(".menu").fadeToggle( "fast" );

})
```

```css
.top {
        background-color:#F8F8F8;
        width:100%;
        height:60px;
       -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 8px -200px rgba(178,176,176,1);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 8px -200px rgba(178,176,176,1);
        box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 8px -200px rgba(178,176,176,1);
}

.profile_img {
    max-width: 28px;
    max-height: 32px;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.content
{
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
 width: 250px;
 margin-left:30px;
}
.user_text {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:20px;
    vertical-align:20%;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.admin-panel
{
 background: #F8F8F8;
 width: 240px;
 height: 40px;
 color: #888;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 font: bold 13px Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 41px;
 cursor: default;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
}

.down
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 10px 14px 0 0;
 border: none;
 color: #888888;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.down:hover { color: #555555; }

.user_text { cursor: pointer; }

.menu a
{
 display: block;
 background: #F8F8F8;
 width: 240px;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 font: bold 13px Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
 color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.4 );
 line-height: 40px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.menu a:nth-child( 2 )
{
 border-top-left-radius: 3px;
 border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.menu a:last-child
{
 border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.menu a:hover { color: #555555; }

.menu a:hover > .octicon { color: #555555; }

.arrow
{
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin-left: 15px;
 border-left: 7px solid transparent;
 border-right: 7px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 9px solid #F8F8F8;
}
.menu { display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="admin-panel"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wmyOI5f.jpg" class="profile_img"><b class="user_text">Curtis Jackson</b></div> <span class="down"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/bLXw2RL.png"></span>
                    <div class="menu">
                        <div class="arrow"></div> 
                        <a href="#">Edit User</a> 
                        <a href="#">Worker Statistics</a> 
                        <a href="#">Settings</a> 
                        <a href="#">Logout</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
$( ".cog, .admin-text" ).on( "click", function()
```

With this line:

```
$( ".admin-panel" ).on( "click", function()
```

... and it will work.

You can check it on Codepen: http://codepen.io/catalin586/pen/LRbELV

You may also want to add a display none by default to your menu:

```
.menu {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.down` & `.user_text`

Try it:

```js
$( ".down, .user_text" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( ".menu" ).stop().fadeToggle( "fast" );
});
```

```css
/*MENU CSS------------*/
.top {
        background-color:#F8F8F8;
        width:100%;
        height:60px;
       -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 8px -200px rgba(178,176,176,1);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 8px -200px rgba(178,176,176,1);
        box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 8px -200px rgba(178,176,176,1);
}

.profile_img {
    max-width: 28px;
    max-height: 32px;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.content
{
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
 width: 250px;
 margin-left:30px;
}
.user_text {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:20px;
    vertical-align:20%;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.admin-panel
{
 background: #F8F8F8;
 width: 240px;
 height: 40px;
 color: #888;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 font: bold 13px Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 41px;
 cursor: default;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
}

.down
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 10px 14px 0 0;
 border: none;
 color: #888888;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.down:hover { color: #555555; }

.user_text { cursor: pointer; }

.menu a
{
 display: block;
 background: #F8F8F8;
 width: 240px;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 font: bold 13px Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
 color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.4 );
 line-height: 40px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.menu a:nth-child( 2 )
{
 border-top-left-radius: 3px;
 border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.menu a:last-child
{
 border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.menu a:hover { color: #555555; }

.menu a:hover > .octicon { color: #555555; }

.arrow
{
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin-left: 15px;
 border-left: 7px solid transparent;
 border-right: 7px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 9px solid #F8F8F8;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300">
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

<div class="top">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="admin-panel"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wmyOI5f.jpg" class="profile_img">
                      <b class="user_text">Curtis Jackson</b>
                  </div> 
                  <span class="down">
                    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bLXw2RL.png">
                  </span>
                    <div class="menu">
                        <div class="arrow"></div> 
                        <a href="#">Edit User</a> 
                        <a href="#">Worker Statistics</span></a> 
                        <a href="#">Settings</span></a> 
                        <a href="#">Logout</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .cog and change .admin-text to .admin-panel

```
$( ".cog, .admin-text" ).on( "click", function()
```

to

```
$( ".admin-panel" ).on( "click", function()
```

Hope it helps!

```js
$( ".admin-panel" ).on( "click", function()
{
  $( ".menu" ).stop().fadeToggle( "fast" );
});
```

```css
/*MENU CSS------------*/
.top {
        background-color:#F8F8F8;
        width:100%;
        height:60px;
       -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 8px -200px rgba(178,176,176,1);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 8px -200px rgba(178,176,176,1);
        box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 8px -200px rgba(178,176,176,1);
}

.profile_img {
    max-width: 28px;
    max-height: 32px;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.content
{
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
 width: 250px;
 margin-left:30px;
}
.user_text {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:20px;
    vertical-align:20%;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.admin-panel
{
 background: #F8F8F8;
 width: 240px;
 height: 40px;
 color: #888;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 font: bold 13px Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 41px;
 cursor: default;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
}

.down
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 10px 14px 0 0;
 border: none;
 color: #888888;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.down:hover { color: #555555; }

.user_text { cursor: pointer; }

.menu a
{
 display: block;
 background: #F8F8F8;
 width: 240px;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 font: bold 13px Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
 color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.4 );
 line-height: 40px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.menu a:nth-child( 2 )
{
 border-top-left-radius: 3px;
 border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.menu a:last-child
{
 border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.menu a:hover { color: #555555; }

.menu a:hover > .octicon { color: #555555; }

.arrow
{
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin-left: 15px;
 border-left: 7px solid transparent;
 border-right: 7px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 9px solid #F8F8F8;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300">
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

<div class="top">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="admin-panel"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/wmyOI5f.jpg" class="profile_img"><b class="user_text">Curtis Jackson</b></div> <span class="down"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/bLXw2RL.png"></span>
                    <div class="menu">
                        <div class="arrow"></div> 
                        <a href="#">Edit User</a> 
                        <a href="#">Worker Statistics</span></a> 
                        <a href="#">Settings</span></a> 
                        <a href="#">Logout</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not having any elements with classes either cog or admin-text. You are using onclick on these. The codePen example which you have provided contains an element with admin-text class

Comment: He missed admin-text class right. then why down vote?

Answer (score -2):

you can use fadeIn and fadeOut in jquery
see the documentation in jquery